# Concatenating multitrack .wav files using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav, sox

I have 32bit .wav files with around 6 channels, segmented into chunks of 2.15GB. I want to merge the files sequentially, retaining the individual channels. I would assume something like:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i filenames.txt -c:a flac output.flac
```

would work, but it does not.
Anyone have an idea on what to do, I do not have a lot of experience with these command line tools...

Comment: Hello, you forgot to show filenames.txt.